# Privacy: VPN and DNS

Tags: vpn, dns, privacy, privacy-protection, nordvpn

I'm using a VPN for privacy purposes. If I ensure that the DNS requests are sent through the VPN I can select whatever DNS Server I like? Is there any advantage to using the DNS Server provided by the VPN provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only advantages of using the DNS provided by your VPN provider are

1. The DNS is at the same location as your VPN server and should have the same or similar latency as your VPN provider. If you use a different DNS then packets may be going from you to your VPN provider and *then* to another server at a different geographic location.
2. The DNS server will have the same or similar privacy policy policy to your VPN provider.

Neither of these should be considered to force you to make use of the VPN providers DNS.

DNS requests are a tiny part of the initial setup of a request for a Web page, and once you have done a request your computer itself will cache it for a period of time rather than constantly asking "Who is Google.com?" So it will only really affect the first time you connect to a server on any given day.

As long as you are using a well supported and provisioned DNS server you will be unlikely to notice any real speed difference. Google DNS and NordVPN DNS will likely have at most 100ms difference and as mentioned you'll only see it happen occasionally rather than every connection.

The other point is that you keep all your "leaking traffic" such as location requests within your VPN provider. It's up to you how paranoid you are about security and privacy. All anyone outside your VPN provider will know is that *someone* at that VPN network is requesting DNS resolution, it's unlikely to be a big security risk.

Comment: As a small addition: it's not just about connection speed and anonymity, for example, update frequencies reflect changes made on authoritative DNS servers for a certain domain this might be a more significant issue. As I said it depends on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general answer here. It depends on the setup of the DNS server and especially the aspects that concern you, which can be privacy, speed, availability etc.

I assume you are after the privacy aspect. As long as you're sending the DNS requests via the VPN you should be fine using any DNS server. Other than that you need to specify your question a little more.